# Vocabulary Question: Indexing in Time Series

Tags: time-series

I'm reading the paper *A review on time series data mining* written by Tak-chung Fu, available here: https://zero.sci-hub.se/6989/6ea2f1e72559e22ed0a799f59f38fbb2/fu2011.pdf

One term that gets used without a definition is "indexing", For instance in section 2 (Time series representation and indexing), the author writes:

> In the context of time series data mining, the fundamental
> problem is how to represent the time series data. One of the
> common approaches is transforming the time series to another
> domain for dimensionality reduction followed by an indexing
> mechanism.

I understand the idea of dimensionality reduction. Supposing you have a list of real-valued points ordered in time as in $(t_1, v_1) \ldots (t_n, v_n)$, and you wish to reduce it to an ordered representation $(t_{i_{1}}, v_{i_{1}}) \ldots ((t_{i_{k}}, v_{i_{k}}))$ where $k << n$. But what does the term *indexing* mean in this context?
Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In time series data mining we have a database of time series that we want to query in some way. Answering many of the queries involves finding a time series, or a sub-sequence in a time series that matches or is similar to a query time series. The simplistic way of doing this is simply to search through the entire database to find the matching time series. Obviously this is time-consuming, especially if the database is large. Indexing is a method of organising the time series database in a way that allows us to find the matching time series by only searching a small subset of the time series.